# ?platform=hootsuite after my url and link also got indexed by Google

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, duplicates, google-index, hootsuite

I'm using Hootsuite to publish social media messages for my site.

I was just checking Google links and I saw Google was indexing a link of mine twice. Like this:

www.website.com/page/page-2/

and

www.website.com/page/page-2/?platform=hootsuite

Same page, same content.

I realy dont want this and I curious how I can prevent this from happening. Anybody got this issue too?

Comment: Hi do you have a url for us to see? I'm wondering if you have that unwanted hootsuite link in your sitemap.xml file?

Comment: it is not in my sitemap. You can see what I mean here - https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:https:%2F%2Fwww.hostingportaal.nl%2Fproviders%2Ftilaa%2Freviews%2F

Comment: Your site does not have a sitemap: https://www.hostingportaal.nl/sitemap.xml, it's here where you tell google what your web pages are.

Comment: I do have a site map: /sitemap_index.xml and /hosting-portaal-providers.xml

Comment: Can you add your url back please so I can check your sitemap?